# Prove $q_n \alpha - p_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_{n+1}q_n +q_{n-1}}$

Tags: continued-fractions

I would like to prove that given any $\alpha = [a_0; a_1 \ldots] \in \mathbb{R}$, with:
\begin{equation}
\alpha_n = [a_n; a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_0]\\
\frac{p_n}{q_n} = [a_0; a_1, \ldots, a_n]
\end{equation}
Then we have the following;
\begin{equation}
q_n \alpha - p_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_{n+1}q_n +q_{n-1}}
\end{equation}

I have started by deriving the relationship that $\alpha_n = \frac{q_n}{q_{n-1}}$, but I'm not sure if (or how) this might help. Also, I know that 
\begin{equation}
p_n q_{n-1} - p_{n-1}q_n = (-1)^{n+1}
\end{equation}
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is written properly? As it is, the LHS could be irrational while the RHS is certainly rational.

Comment: I've just checked the problem and it seems to be correct. That's a good point though, I didn't see that! Suppose $\alpha$ was a rational number then...

Comment: Looking at it, the most likely thing for it to mean is $\alpha_{n}$ on the LHS. Perhaps try that?

Comment: I have tried to prove that the equality will hold for $\alpha_n$ instead of $\alpha$ using induction, but I run into a problem. For a base induction step I try to prove it holds for $n=0$. Using the values $q_{-1}=0, q_{-2} =1, p_{-1}=1, p_{-2} =0$ and the formula I derived above, we end up having to divide by 0... (not sure if I'm doing it right though).